# Basic problem: Parse two-column text file into variables for use in a for loop

Tags: powershell

I'm eager to learn Powershell, but don't have much time to get this working. I believe this is a basic issue that could have several solutions.

I have a text file which could easily be converted into a csv if necessary.  It contains two columns (no headers):

```
ABC12345:Name1
ABC12346:Name2
```

etc.

I need these columns read in one line at a time in a for loop and each column entry placed into a variable for execution.  At the moment I have:

```
$Contents = Get-Content "d:\Filename.txt" | ForEach-Object {
$Var1 = $Contents[0].split(":")[1]
$Var2 = $Contents[1].split(":")[1]
Run-command -param1 $Var1 -param2 $Var2
}
```

Unsurprisingly I'm getting an error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Char] does not contain a method named 'split'.
```

I'm likely completely wrong with the array usage and formatting.  Am I over-complicating this?

Comment: when in a `ForEach-Object` scriptblock, you need to use `$_` to refer to the current pipeline item. you are using the $Var that you are assigning the output to ... that aint gonna work. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat the file as a CSV, the you can get the items like this:

`Import-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Path .\test.csv -Header 'Var1','Var2'`

This will output an object for each line with properties `Var1` and `Var2`.  Thus your code could be:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Path .\test.csv -Header 'Var1','Var2' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    Run-Command -Param1 $_.Var1 -Param2 $_.Var2
  }
```